# Visual Studio 2017RC xamarin.android returns "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError", VS2015 does'nt?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I have just got VS2017RC installed and opened my existing Xamarin.Forms project. When I rebuild the project, It returns me an error in the Android project.

```
    Error       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. Consider increasing the value of $(JavaMaximumHeapSize). Java ran out of memory while executing 'java.exe -jar
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.2\\lib\dx.jar" --no-strict --dex --output=obj\Debug\android\bin obj\Debug\android\bin\classes 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.0\mono.android.jar"
```

I am familiar with the error. There is solution out there but I dont understand why when I build it with VS2015, I dont get this error. 
Could it be something to do with referencing to MonoAndroid\v7.0, I am newbie on this. I am not sure what is v7.0 but I think that this is installed with VS 2017 together. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to increase your memory:

> Android Project -> Options -> Android Build -> Advanced ----
>   Additional Options: Java Heap Size

and you can set to `512mb` or `1G`

Comment: this is not my question indeed. I know that this is the solution but I dont understand why this happens in vs2017 only.